# MPMoviePlayerController - streaming works on 3GS, not on anything pre-3GS

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am having some serious issues and annoyances with `MPMoviePlayerController`. In my app you can watch trailers for some movies in .mov format.

I have tested with a friend and had users report that it does not work on their device, which are all 3G. I have tested on my own, a 3GS and playback works fine. I have tried on a 1st gen iPhone and it doesn't work. So I am lead to believe it's a memory issue, and that it's simply stopping the playback and returning to the previous screen.

Below is the code I use to launch the player, which is straight out of the MoviePlayer example from Apple.

```
MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:trailerURL]];
if (mp) {
    self.moviePlayer = mp;
    [mp release];
    [self.moviePlayer play];
}
```

I have tried to check the NSError from the notifications, but the only thing I get is "An unknown playback error occurred" for both the `localizedDescription` and `localizedRecoverySuggestion`, making it impossible to figure out exactly why it's not working.

I have seen many examples of people who just have issues with the movie player, but it's starting to annoy me that it sometimes seem to work fine and other times it just doesn't (again, appearing like a memory issue).

Thanks for any help/feedback provided

Answer (score 0):

Are all the phones running at least 3.0?

Comment: Yes. Tested on 3.1.3 and 3.1.2, same issue.

Comment: Nothing on the system log? Does the Instruments CPU/memory profiler tell you anything?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also having strange issues while trying to playback some remote (http://) stream with the player. The issue does not seem to come from iPhone 3G or iPhone 3Gs but I get different behavior between 3G network and wifi : it goes fine with Wifi and I get the same ""An unknown playback error occurred" from the notification center during the preload phasis when I try to play using 3G network :/ Does anybody experience the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

I have submitted Bug ID 8647495 for this on 11/10/2010 - Dan